# Spotify - How to create a playlist including certain albums from an artist

Tags: excel, spotify

**The objective:** I Really love discovering music so I am trying to create a playlist to discover more songs from artists a user already likes (because you know, sometimes we just add a song or two from an artist and don´t take the time to explore the rest of his/her work).

**The project:** copying my Spotify songs in a simple Excel doc. I am able to determine the following:

1. Name of the artists from which I only have 1 song
2. Name of the artists from which I have 
   between 2 and 4 songs
3. Name of the artists from which I have 5 or more songs

Now, based on these results/inputs I would like to create the following playlists:

1. "If I only have 1 song from an artist = Create a playlist with his TOP10"
2. "If I have between 2 and 4 songs from an artist = Create a playlist with his TOP10 and all albums these songs are from"
3. "If I have 5 or more songs from an artist = Create a playlist with all songs from this artist"

Is there a way to do so?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your number 2, ***"If I have between 2 and 4 songs from an artist = Create a playlist with his TOP10 and all albums these songs are from"***, you'll have to do many API calls but it's pretty easy to do :

Once you have your artist id (you'll find it with this endpoint "*[GET https://api.spotify.com/v1/search?q={artist_name}&type=artist](https://developer.spotify.com/web-api/search-item/)*")

You can ask for its top ten tracks with the endpoint "*[GET https://api.spotify.com/v1/artists/{id}/top-tracks](https://developer.spotify.com/web-api/get-artists-top-tracks/)*"

Now you have your tracks object, you can get their album id, and get Album's Tracks using this endpoint "*[GET https://api.spotify.com/v1/albums/{id}/tracks](https://developer.spotify.com/web-api/get-albums-tracks/)*"

I hope it'll help you!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure if you're tied to excel, but based on this question I don't know how much research you have personally done.

To start with I would direct you to [Spotify's API](https://developer.spotify.com/web-api/).

As far as implementation goes, you might want to look at using a [scope](https://developer.spotify.com/web-api/using-scopes/) to read a user's music, I would use the user-library-read one.

You could then proceed to examine the library as you've detailed above and [add](https://developer.spotify.com/web-api/add-tracks-to-playlist/) or [replace](https://developer.spotify.com/web-api/replace-playlists-tracks/) its tracks.

Spotify's API should have any further information you need if you want to implement this.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Erasyn!

Well, I - of course - looked into the Spotify API:

Number 1 seems feasible based on my research

Number 2 is what worries me and unless I've missed something in your answer, it seems like I am still going to have to worry about it ´_´

Number 3 can be done but there is no straightforward way to do it according to my research so I'm looking for a new way to implement it.